# Explicit SQL in PHP

Tags: php, sql, literals

I'm wondering if there is a way to run explicit SQL strings inside of PHP.
I know PHP has a bunch of handling methods (sql_connect(...) is an example; however I have memories of using LINQ in C# and being able to run specific, concatenated strings as literal SQL.

Does anyone happen to know of a way to do that using PHP?

An example of a query I'd want to run:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, numberOfPosts, posts.subject
FROM Persons p
INNER JOIN Posts posts ON posts.personID = p.ID
WHERE id = @currentUser;
```

where "@currentUser" would be a variable that would be set to a currently logged in user on a PHP-based site.

Thanks ahead of time for any help!

Comment: @max4ever: That doesn't "run" the SQL.

Comment: jesus ... just do a mysqli_query() with escaped parameters then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your example the best would be to make use of [PDO Prepared-Statements](http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)